# Find factor by target and given range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a range on values, starting from `A1`, let's say:

[image]

Then I have a target, let's say: `43543`

Currently I am inputting values into Excel sheet and writing to cell `B1` formula `=CEILING(A1*$C$14, 1)` then dragging it down. In cell `C14` I have a factor, let's say `1.54`, then I am starting to manually adjust this factor in order to achieve `43543` as a result. In my example case I tried about 30 times until I have found that it should be `6.0588`

My question is: is there some formula that can automatically calculate this factor?

I have tried several solutions I have found, but can't get this working.

[image]

I can do iterations with VBA, but it is taking quite some time, especially for bigger numbers. Below is an example. Sometimes I need to use `0.0000001` and it is quite long procedure... Is there some faster approach?

```
Sub FindFactor()
    Dim factor As Double
    Dim targetValue As Long
    
    targetValue = Range("C2").Value
    
    'Loop through possible factor values
    For factor = 1 To 10 Step 0.0000001
    '... etc
```

Maybe one approach would be to set step higher in the begging and then while getting closer to target to set it smaller? Is it possible?

Comment: You might consider using Solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel has a built in feature called goalSeek that does this fast.  Set up your worksheet so all the formulas are set.  It seems that you have your formulas in column B and then your target is the sum of all the values from multiplying column A by the factor.  Use this general procedure:

1. Select the summation cell target.
2. Go to data tab>What-if Analysis>Goal Seek...
3. In the set cell entry, set it to the summation target cell
4. in the to value entry, set it to your target value of 43543
5. In the by changing cell entry, set it to the factor cell.
6. click ok.

This will do what your macro does but faster... They have algorithms to do this type of thing... The result is what the factor should be.